# Image becomes bigger than parent although max-height is set to 100%

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a `<img>` tag to show a photo over another div, as some sort of overlay. However, the image won't scale to be inside of it's parent div (which is the body of the page). Instead it overflows the body. When I set `overflow: hidden;` to the body, you can't scroll over the page. I want the image to be full-height and fitted within the body (without enlarging the body).

This is basically the structure of the page:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="imgContainer">
         <img class="actualImage" />
      </div>
      <div class="restOfBody">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the css:

```
body {
  background-image: url(*some background photo*)
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.imgContainer {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.actualImage {
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

This is basically what is happening now:
[The image that is drawn over the text right now, pushes the page down so far, that it actually exceeds the body of the html.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT3i7.jpg)

Comment: Why not set it as background-image, like in your css?

Comment: Because I want to have multiple layers. I want to have the following format:
Background
Overlay
Image
Text

In this way, the text will come over the image, but a coloured div will be put under the image (just like the background will be put under the image).

Comment: Please provide [minimal, complete, reproducible, code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

height in % will not work till you will use meta for height,
ok please use overflow:hidden at the place of overflow:none

Comment: use meta for height in head as same as for width
then it will work

Comment: I'm sorry for that, that's actually what I meant. (The overflow: none/hidden part). I'm not quite sure what you mean by meta for height?

Comment: please use in <head></head>::--
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1.0">
And then you can write max-height=100%

Answer (score 0):

make your image as background-image. I think it would be better.

Comment: Since I want to use the z-index to make different layers, this is not an option. Thanks for your comment though, normally it would be a great option

Answer (score 0):

Add a container in your body as shown,

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgContainer">
            <img class="actualImage" src="banner.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and do this in css

```
.container {
    width: 200px;/*sample width*/
    height: 200px;/*sample height*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-height: inherit;
}
```

The `.container` is responsible for setting a boundary and by using `overflow: hidden`, prevent content inside `.container` to overlap. While in the case of `.imgContainer` make sure the position is relative to container, absolute will pull itself out the flow, which is not safe in your case.

Comment: I hope this will help

Comment: But how do I make sure that I responsively know how large my container should be?

Comment: You can use media queries